# Wordpress Search result page display entire content

Tags: wordpress

I have a signifiantly big problem up there.

I'm trying to design my search restult page on WordPress, but if it comes that the search find a page with the keyword I just entered, it display the entire page instead of the title();

**My code**

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @package miller
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">

        <main id="int_top_main" class="internal blue_top" style="min-height:80px;">

            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2 class="page_title uppercase"><span class="parent_page">Search results</h2>

                <div id="infinite_blue_top_bar"></div>
            </div>

        </main><!-- #main -->

        <div id="int_content_main" class="internal">

            <div class="wrapper physician_headline">

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php the_title(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <h2><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'miller' ); ?></h2>


                        <div class="page-content">

                            <?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>

                                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search terms. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'miller' ); ?></p>

                            <?php else : ?>

                                <p><?php _e( 'It seems we can&rsquo;t find what you&rsquo;re looking for. Perhaps searching can help.', 'miller' ); ?></p>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div><!-- .page-content -->

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>

    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If it finds nothing, it will go into the else: but if it do finds something they display all the pages (fullpage) of what it finds out there.

It should only display the_title(); but no..

Even if I completly destruct the search.php file it stills automaticly goes to the "suggested" page.

First time I am getting this kind of thing and I do not know how to solve it :(

Answer (score 0):

It's calling for the post before the title, which is why it pulls for the full post.

Try:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_title();  ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : ?>
```

Comment: I'll test this.. Meanwhile, all my problems got solved by placing this line at the end of my header.php `<?php rewind_posts(); ?>`